# How to get action bar show in android

Tags: android

```
public class MainActi`enter code here`vity extends Activity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`enter code here`
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActionBar actionBar=getActionBar();`enter code here`
        actionBa`.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. [Take a look](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

actionBar is deprecated you should use Toolbar...

first create new layout named "app_bar.xml"

and type this codes on it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="150dp"
      android:paddingTop="@dimen/top_padding"
      android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

then in your mainactivity type this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    public Toolbar toolbar;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

   }}
```